# Error: TypeScript emitted no output for /frontend/src/index.tsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

При компиляции webpack получаю такую ошибку:

```
Hash: 58d821e2954fef96ec41
Version: webpack 4.41.0
Time: 3249ms
Built at: 09/27/2019 6:39:50 PM
 2 assets
Entrypoint main = main.js main.js.map
[0] ./src/index.tsx 526 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/index.tsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
Error: TypeScript emitted no output for //frontend/src/index.tsx.
    at makeSourceMapAndFinish (/frontend/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:80:15)
    at successLoader (/frontend/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/inde

x.js:68:9)
    at Object.loader (/frontend/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:22:12)

ERROR in /frontend/src/react-app-env.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /frontend/src/react-app-env.ts(1,1)
      TS1208: All files must be modules when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided.
```

Вот мой `webpac.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    mode: "production",

    entry: './src/index.tsx',

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".d.ts"]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "ts-loader"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                enforce: "pre",
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "source-map-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    }
};
```

Вот `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCh

eck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Вот `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.2",
    "@types/jest": "24.0.18",
    "@types/node": "12.7.8",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.9.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "ts-loader": "^6.1.2",
    "typescript": "^3.6.3",
    "webpack": "^4.41.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9"
  }
}
```

Я вообще хз, что делать.

Comment: что это за файл _/frontend/src/react-app-env.ts_? что в нем?

Comment: Попробуйте удалить из `tsconfig.json` строку `"noEmit": true`